# Cannot create Stored Procedure on remote MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I am using a web service to execute SQL queries on my remote MySQL server and it is working just great when I execute normal SQL queries of Select/Update/Delete/Drop/etc. But when I try to create a Stored Procedure using following query it fails.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    
    PROCEDURE `GetAllCategory`()
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM category;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

My MySQL remote server supports SP as I can create them in PhpMyAdmin but now through the web service.

I am getting following error from the web service I am using:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.40
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: LiteSpeed

Please guide as to how to solve this problem.

TIA

Comment: Citate the error message (fully, without any edition).

Comment: what do you mean by "it fails"? Please provide the error message

Comment: 'My MySQL remote server supports SP as I can create them in PhpMyAdmin.'' - What are you using to create SP remotely if not phpmyadmin? and if phpmyadmin works to create sp on remote server why not just use that?

Comment: @P.Salmon, My software created the queries to be executed and then I am using a web service to execute my queries on server. I am not using PhpMyAdmin to create SP.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetAllCategory`$$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `GetAllCategory`()

BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM category;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: An explanation of why you think this would work would be useful (and maybe deter downvotes)

Comment: @danish islam, Adding DROP does not help.